# Linked list and double pointers

Tags: c, linked-list

In the below code, I am trying to insert a node after a particular node. In the function, I will be giving as input the address of the previous node after which I want to insert the new node. The problem is in the 10th line of function insertAfter() - it says I cannot access *prev_ref->next.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 struct node
 {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
 };

 void push(struct node **head_ref, int data)
{

struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ;
newNode->next= *head_ref;
newNode->data= data;
*head_ref= newNode;

}


void insertAfter(struct node **prev_ref, int data)
{
if(*prev_ref==NULL)
{
    printf("prev ref cant be null");
    return;
}
struct node * newNode;
newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ;
newNode->next= *prev_ref->next;
newNode->data= data;
*prev_ref->next= newNode;

}


 void printList(struct node *node)
    {
     while (node != NULL)
      {
       printf(" %d ", node->data);
       node = node->next;
    }
   }

main()
{
struct node* head = NULL;
push(&head, 7);
push(&head, 1);
insertAfter(&head, 8);
printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
printList(head);
 getchar();
 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Does (*prev_ref)->next help ?

Comment: Please paste the code for `struct node` and the complete compiler error message.

Comment: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know `(*p).s` is equivalent to `p->s` ? I would suggest you to try something like `(*prev_ref)->next` or `(**prev_ref).next`

Comment: Tried it . The concept is clear now, yet the error message remains same.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to dereference `prev_ref` three-levels deep instead of two.

`pointer->field` is dereference of a pointer, equivalent to `(*pointer).field`

So, `**prev_ref->next;` is in fact `(***prev_ref).next;`

Either drop one asterisk or use `.` instead of `->`.

EDIT:
You seem to have skipped the parentheses we included in our answers.

`->` has higher precedence than `*`.

The effect is:

`(*prev_ref)->next`

- first uses '*' and finds the memory pointed to by `prev_ref` (let's call it memory location `A`),
- then uses '->' to find memory pointed to by `A`, let's call it `B`,
- then location of the the `next` field of the structure, offset by a set distance from `B`, let's call it `C`
- and finally accesses (reads/writes) the value stored at C.

Now for `*prev_ref->next`

- first, uses `->` and finds the memory pointed to by `prev_ref` (A), just the same
- then the location of the the `next` field of the structure, offset by a set distance from `A`, which happens to be an entirely random location in memory (because A stored a pointer to the structure, not the structure itself); let's call that location D.
- Then it tries to find the memory location at wherever D pointed to, which is entirely random.

Now, the system won't let you do that, because it sees A is not where a structure lies, but where a pointer to a structure lies, hence the error message

And the fundamental reason of your problems is that you use pointers-to-pointers for no good reason. Nothing of this would have happened if you always used plain pointers. `void push(struct node *head_ref, int data)` , `void insertAfter(struct node *prev_ref, int data)`, `prev_ref->next` etc. Managing pointers to pointers is tricky, error-prone (as you've experienced) and in 99% cases completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept . But still i get the same error message. Hence i have pasted the entire code . Also i have given the error message in comments.